# After Refreshing the page , i m loosing the input button field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have js file which has this code in it

```
table = table + '<td class="mytd"><input type="button" style="display:none; width:40px;  color:White;  background-color:#00BFFF;" class="editButton" value="Edit" id="' + obj[i].orderid+ '"/></td>';
```

it gets visible when i make  `('.editButton').show();`  in the same js file .

But after refreshing the page  , Edit button gets invisible .

I don't know where the issue is..

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: style="display:none; <------ that will make your button hidden every time you refresh the page

Comment: because the browser acts like a whiteboard. You erase it and it starts over. It does not magically know you want state to be maintained. You got to code it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
table = table + '<td class="mytd"><input type="button" style="display:none; width:40px;  color:White;  background-color:#00BFFF;" class="editButton" value="Edit" id="' + obj[i].orderid+ '"/></td>';
```

This has `style="display: none"` in the input tag.

So in JS when you are constructing the DOM in that way and append it to the HTML it will hidden by default.

As you said, when you call `('.editButton').show();` its shown to the user.

But when you refresh the page, the DOM is again constructed and all your JS changes will be lost. It doesn't preserve the JS changes and you need to do it again.

That's why its hidden always.

If you try to put

```
$(function() {
// table construction code here
// append to body

('.editButton').show();
});
```

It will show the input box always when the page loads.

Am assuming that you are constructing the table before this line ;)