# input button field gets invisible after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

My js file has this code

```
table = table + '<td class="mytd"><input type="button" style="display:none; width:40px;  color:White;  background-color:#00BFFF;" class="editButton" value="Edit" id="' + obj[i].orderid+ '"/></td>';
```

it creates an edit button . And i also have sessionstorage in my js file ,If user logged in , it keeps the user information even page is refreshed . When i logged in page shows edit button , add button and log out button . 
But after refreshing the page ,  edit button gets invisible.This is where i stack .

Here is my windows load code ;

```
window.onload = function () {


$("#logout-button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#btnTest').css('display', 'block');
    $('#logout-button').css('display', 'none');
    $('#btnInsert').hide();
    $('.editButton').css('display', 'none');
    sessionStorage.clear();
});


var students = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo'));

if (students !== null) {

    $('.editButton').show();
    $('#btnInsert').show();
    $('#logout-button').show();
    $('#btnTest').css('display', 'none');

}
else {
    $('.editButton').hide();
    $('#btnTest').css('display', 'block');
    $('#logout-button').css('display', 'none');
}
```

}

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Did you actually create a new account?

Comment: I just created new account

Comment: And you asked another question under a different account about the same thing...

Comment: Just annoying that a topic is started and you abandoned it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667189/after-refreshing-the-page-i-m-loosing-the-input-button-field#comment36356345_23667189

Comment: maybe `students` is null after refresh?

Comment: i just shared another different question there . The reason is some one drop the question score to -1 thats why i created new account .

Comment: But the question more clear i guess. can you help me with that ? or your answer still same ..?

Comment: @arvic.rivera , it is the reason when user log out ,  it deletes user information from sessionstorage , but my question is , when user logged in , he sees everything he needs , but after refreshs the page , only edit button is invisible but others fine

Comment: @epascarello ,  why you are doing this ?

Comment: @jasonstone please try to move `table = table + '<td class="mytd"><input type="button" style="display:none; width:40px;  color:White;  background-color:#00BFFF;" class="editButton" value="Edit" id="' + obj[i].orderid+ '"/></td>';` to inside the window.onload function before `JSON.parse`...

Comment: I mean, the instructions where you add `table` to the document

Comment: i can't do it , because it is another part of a function .

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!students) {
    $('.editButton').hide();
    $('#btnTest').css('display', 'block');
    $('#logout-button').css('display', 'none');
}
else {
$('.editButton').show();
    $('#btnInsert').show();
    $('#logout-button').show();
    $('#btnTest').css('display', 'none');    
}
```